# How to disable all built-in SSL certificates in wget and just use self-signed one?

Tags: linux, ssl, wget

I would like to use wget (or curl) to connect to my website using only my self signed SSL certificate. The website also has some root CA signed wildcard certificates.

```
wget -O- --ca-certificate=my.pem --ca-directory=/dev/null --certificate=my.pem https://example.com
```

This works on my server with the self signed certificate, but it also establishes a connection to any regular SSL-enabled public website (when changing example.com). So it seems to not disable build-in root CAs.

How can I disable all build-in root CAs in wget so only my private certificate can establish a secure connection and it fails without (to test if the self signed cert is installed correctly)?

Comment: There is a tool called mkcert that might be able to solve the issue with root CAs. https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Comment: A bit off-topic here. See instead there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199372/wget-force-no-default-certificates

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't know what is on-topic on stackoverflow. I don't find a mission statement, SO doesn't have a "homepage". I thought it's for devops in general, to collaborate and share knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Got some help on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655614/openssl-force-no-default-ca-certificates-to-verify-private-signed-certificate): real `openssl s_client` (check with `openssl version`) supports the parameter `-verify_return_error` which will catch certificate verification errors.